# Search for file in folder using php

Tags: php

I am storing user uploaded files like pdf images and txt files in separate folders using my php script i want to retrieve the file names from the folder upload and give the pdf and txt in a group and also way to search for specific file.

I also need to rename the file before to `$ja` variable

```
$ja
$da = date("dmY");
$ja = $uid.$da;

    move_uploaded_file($mi, $uploadpath)
```

also used this code which i found in stack

Example 01:

```
<?php
  // read all files inside the given directory
  // limited to a specific file extension
  $files = glob("./ABC/*.txt");
?>
```

Example 02:

```
<?php
  // perform actions for each file found
  foreach (glob("./ABC/*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
  }
?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with phpmyadmin?

Comment: just u know u guys know php so can help me out right

Comment: @Juhana: thats so nice please help me in renaming the file $mukesh = $app.$ja; echo $mukesh."<br/>"; // If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors if($err == '') { if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) { echo 'File: <b>'. basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']). '</b> successfully uploaded:';

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the scandir(); function will help you

```
<?php
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

now you have array of all files in a location you specified you can use array functions to get your work done

Comment: how to rename a file before upload$mukesh = $app.$ja;

echo $mukesh."<br/>";



  // If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors
  if($err == '') {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) { 
      echo 'File: <b>'. basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']). '</b> successfully uploaded:';

Answer (score 1):

you can try listing the directory with [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), and then filter as you want in the php array of filenames you will get